# MicroSD card on Beagleboard A6 white is only 70 MB?

Tags: beagleboard

I have one of the older A6 revision beagleboard. They advertise that it comes with a 4GB microSD card. I plugged the card to the beagleboard, then plugged the beagleboard to my ubuntu computer via USB. Then I ran

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

as well as

```
lsblk
```

to list the block devices that the system sees. It reported "sdb" drive, size of which is only 70MB, though. I also tried GParted. It also sees only 70MB. Why can't I see the 4GB as advertised? I am trying to install ubuntu on it, but I need more disk space.

EDIT:

The output of: sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe1892732

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      409600   302864678   151227539+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       302866430   976771071   336952321    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       302866432   508022783   102578176   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       508024832   515835903     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       515837952   976771071   230466560    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 73 MB, 73995264 bytes
3 heads, 48 sectors/track, 1003 cylinders, total 144522 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

The relevant part is /dev/sdb

Output of: lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 144.2G  0 part /media/windows
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  97.8G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   3.7G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0 219.8G  0 part /media/data
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdb      8:16   1  70.6M  0 disk
```

Comment: Post the output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a decently common problem that [Windows sometimes formats SDHC cards to 70MB](https://www.google.com/search?q=sd+format+70mb). Download and use [the official formatting tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).

Comment: I never formatted the card. It came like this with the angstrom OS on it. Even if Windows formatted it to only 70MB, wouldn't my linux see the rest of the disk space on the card? Thanks for the link, though. It helped.

Comment: It would unless other out-of-band data structures had been miswritten.

Comment: Not sure what that really means, but gives me some idea. I'll format the card using the above linked tool. Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm - yes, I solved this problem by downloading the formatter software from here https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ and formatted my SD card using it. Then, the size was roughly 3.8 GB. Thanks, Ignacio!